# How to check a part of string with regex pattern in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, ip, phishing

I want to check if a string contains some part that matches a given regex pattern.
My regex is to check for the presence of an IP address, it goes like this

```
regex = '''^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.( 
            25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.( 
            25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.( 
            25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)$'''
```

I want to check if a string like this contains an IP address in it

```
url_string = "http://110.234.52.124/paypal.ca/index.html"
```

since it has an IP address, I want to detect that, how can I do that?

Comment: Use the `re.X` / `re.VERBOSE` flag.

Comment: Also, note your regex matches a full string, you need to replace the `^` and `$` with `\b` and add the `r` prefix before the string literal.

Comment: thanks! , it worked, had been trying that but missed the \b part.

Comment: So, the only problem turned out to be anchors. You just need to check the basic regex concepts then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

regex = "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.( \
            25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.( \
            25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.( \
            25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)"

result = re.search(regex, "http://110.234.52.124/paypal.com")
```

you just need remove ^ and $ and call this function
if result is None that means not found

Comment: @DhruvStan7 But it [matches](https://ideone.com/Yhx4Bp) strings like `http://paypal.com/11111111110.234.52.12456678`, too.

Comment: Ya that would be fine since I want to find the occurrence of IP address, be it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two issues with the regex:

- It contains whitespace that is used as formatting whitespace, a `re.X` or `re.VERBOSE` options are required for it to work
- There are `^` and `$` anchors here that require a full string match. You probably want to use word boundaries, `\b` instead
- If you add word boundaries, the regular string literal will require doubling backslashes, but if you add a `r` prefix and make it a raw string literal, you can just use `\b`
- If there are other dot-separated number strings that are not IPs and need filtering out, you need `(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)` at the start instead of `^` and `(?!\.?\d)` at the end instead of `$`.

You can use

```py
import re

regex = r'''\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.( 
            25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.( 
            25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.( 
            25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b'''
url_string = "http://110.234.52.124/paypal.ca/index.html"
print( bool(re.search(regex, url_string, re.X)) )
# => True
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FWfs4p)

However, you may define an octet pattern as a variable, and build a pattern dynamically removing the need to use `re.X` and that long pattern:

```py
import re
o = r'(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)'
regex = fr'\b{o}(?:\.{o}){{3}}\b'
# OR regex = fr'(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.){o}(?:\.{o}){{3}}(?!\.?\d)'
url_string = "http://110.234.52.124/paypal.ca/index.html"
print( bool(re.search(regex, url_string, re.X)) )
# => True
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fAh2JC). Note the double braces around the `{{3}}` (in an f-string, literal braces are defined with double braces).

Comment: Yes, the issue was point no 2, i was missing th /b part, now it worked. Thanks !